# Tag to request P&T's attention

Tags: discussion

Of course the P&T team can't check in on every question asked here, but some question need special attention by the team.

Questions like these for example:

- [Cache invalidation to automatically update all cached template content?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/309/177) (Questions changed to feature discussion in the comments)
- [Can I extend entries listing views (currently or in the future)?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/412/can-i-extend-entries-listing-views-currently-or-in-the-future) (Got answered, but a comment from the team on future plans would be great)
- [Updating all entries URIs after changing entry URL format](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/406/updating-all-entries-uris-after-changing-entry-url-format) (Changed from Question to possible support request)

That's why I'd like to propose a tag like `p&t-attention-request` or `status-something`.

This tag would get added if:

- A question has become a discussion about a new feature.
- A 'State-of-Craft' information are needed.
- A question could be a bug-report.
- Multiple answers didn't solve the question, but a team member could possibly solve it.

After resolving/answering/commenting.. the tag would be removed from the question, to keep everything clean.

I'd like to know if that's something the P&T team and community would find reasonable, and if so in what other cases that tag would make sense?

*(Assuming of course that the tag doesn't get abused for normal questions)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read each of those questions you listed, but in each case there's just nothing I could say to contribute.

In the first two questions, others already said what I would have said, and in the 3rd, that became more of a bug report, so the question should probably be removed from the site. (We're working with that person privately on his issue.)

We're not going to make promises about future features on this site; I don't think that's in the spirit of the site. If someone needs to know how to do something *today*, me saying that we’re considering that for a future release won’t help them. It will only discourage others from thinking creatively about the problem, and maybe even writing a plugin that provides a solution.

Anyway, I don’t think a special tag to grab our attention is necessary. If you *really* want to get our input on something, and we aren’t answering it here, ask us somewhere else, like [Twitter](https://twitter.com/craftcms), [G+](https://plus.google.com/communities/106505340287442511226), [Craft Chat](http://chat.buildwithcraft.com/), or email.

Comment: I propose the tag "batsignal". ;)

Comment: More like "freewhiskey".

Comment: “freewhiskey” would definitely do the trick.

Comment: We should open a place where P+T can trade (bounty) points for whiskey!

Answer (score 2):

This question needs that tag! :) Good question.

For my part I think not, unless Pixel & Tonic specifically wants to take that on.

I think it could get overwhelming for there to be an expectation of an official answer from P&T on feature-request-like questions. Or on questions the community couldn't definitively answer for there to be an expectation that Pixel & Tonic step in and provide the definitive or official answer. I'm not against them doing that of course! I'm just not sure it would be best to set the expectation with a tag.

On the other hand, it *could* be a useful way for P&T to provide feedback or official responses. And you make a really good point that there are special questions. Overall I just lean toward not having these tags because it makes it more like official support rather than community support. I'm definitely curious to hear what others (and P&T!) think.

Comment: I agree that it could look like official support, but if the community uses it only on a few questions as a 'non-mandatory kindly request'™, do you think it would make the site appear more official?

Comment: :) I am on board with 'non-mandatory kindly request'™. That seems about right and is not too official.

Comment: ...but I think Brandon's answer is spot-on.

Comment: Yes after reading it I agree. With G+ and Craft Chat, a tag could make thinks even more complex.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that amazes me about P&T is its ability to be seemingly omnipotent, swooping in wherever a question needs authoritative answering.

In fact, every time I'm working with Craft I can almost feel Brandon, Brad, and Andris watching and quietly groaning.

So it seems to me like an attention-getting tag is unnecessary.